# Issue running python script every 24 hours using cron job

Tags: python, cron

I have been trying to run a Python script that updates a Twitter bot and should run every day to make a post. I can run this without any problems conventionally using terminal (I'm on Mac) and I believe this cron job should work too:

`30 10 * * * cd /Users/myname/documents/Python/fpltwitterbot && /Users/myname/opt/anaconda3/bin/python main.py`

Nothing happens when the script is supposed to run, no tweet, no error message, nothing.

I have followed a tutorial and given cron and terminal permissions to be able to run properly so I'm very confused.

Any help is greatly appreciated thank you :D

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: sorry I've just done an update, because I forgot the issue, silly me. The issue is that nothing happens when the script is supposed to run and I was hoping to get help if my syntax or anything else is wrong here :)

Comment: Its a PATH issue i guess. The main.py file is not registered in your path and therefore not found. Either add it to the path or add the full path to your cronjob: your/path/main.py

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know what your problem is but, I guess you did't set the `PATH`.

Try this,

1. Run `printenv | grep "PATH"`. (check your PATH)
2. Add `PATH` to your crontab

```
PATH=/your/path

*/1 * * * * your_command
```

P.S
You can get a log from python script like
`Users/myname/opt/anaconda3/bin/python main.py >> /log/file/path 2>&1`